# How do I add a data label from a third column into a Google Sheets pie chart?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, label, spreadsheet, pie-chart

In Google Sheets I have two columns, for the type of expense and the amount in that expense. I was able to make that into a pie chart, but I have a separate small table for the total budget and the amount of money remaining. I want to add the amount of money remaining to the pie chart, but I'm not sure how to because it is in a separate column. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would you share a copy of your file?

Comment: see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125191/186471

Comment: As @KrzysztofDołęgowski mentioned it'd be helpful for the community if you shared a Spreadsheet as example because we don't know hich kind of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use several ranges for pie chart. If you want to combine this data, you have to make a separate table somewhere in your sheet and feed your chart from there. For example - if your main data is in a1:b10 and additional (small table) is in f20:g23, you can make an additional sheet and combine it there using: ={a1:b10;f20:g23} then use this range for your pie chart.